# Rails undefined method `user_index_path`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and working my way through the Rails Tutorial.  Early on, I realized that I accidentally created my model as `Users` rather than `User`, so I've been going with that ever since.

It hasn't been an issue until I tried to implement the sign up page, and now whether going to pages or running the test `visit signup_path` for the sign up page, I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `users_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9e3e1d91b8>:0x007f9e3e1d1ff8>
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong here.  When I run `rake routes` I get the following:

```
~/Coding/rails_projects/sample_app (sign-up*) ☔  rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
     root GET    /                         static_pages#home
     help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
    about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
  contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
```

From that output, it looks to me like there should be a method `users_index_path`.

If it helps, my `Users` controller is the following:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = Users.new
  end

  def show
    @user = Users.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Using Rails 4.0.5.

Output from a page giving me the error:

[image]

Please keep in mind `users_index_path` is being called by Rails and not by me.

Comment: What happens if you change your `User model` file to `user.rb`, then in your controller's `new` action call `@user = User.new`. Your other directories and tables should be fine because they are supposed to be plural. your controller should be `users_controller`, and even your database table name should be plural like so `create_table :users do |t|`.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.  Simply renaming the file didn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with

```
users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
      POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
```

you'll have a `users_path` method that will generate the `/users` path. That path will lead to either the `index` action (with a GET request) or the `create` action (with a POST request).

Under the hood, `form_for @user` will call the `users_path` method and set things up to fire a POST on submit (when `@user` is a new record). The URL helper method is calculated dynamically from the class name. This is ok if you're using Rails' defaults, but if you've defined custom routes you'll need to specify the URL explicitly.

With this out of the way, let's look at your problem.

A model with a plural name, e.g. `class Users`, will confuse rails.
When you pass `@user` to `form_for`, Rails will look at the class name, notice that it's a plural word, and try its best to deal with the ambiguity.
Normally it would be `user_path` for singular routes (show, update, delete) and `users_path` for the plural ones (index, create). Here, however, `users_path` must be used for the singular routes, and Rails will fallback to use `users_index_path` for `index` and `create`.

This would be all right.... but you have defined the routes using the default statement, probably with something like

```
resources :users
```

Which is correct, but not compatible with your model name.

Either rename your routes (bad) or rename your model (good).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I'm having trouble figuring out what the consequences of renaming the model are--how to generate a full list of all of the files and references that will have to be changed from `users` to `user`, and how to know when it should be plural and when it should be singular.  Is there a command to generate this?

Comment: you'll also need to rename the DB table... the best thing would be to rollback the migration, go back to a previous commit, and re-generate the model

Comment: There's no way I can go back to a previous commit; it's too far back.

Comment: well, if you're following Michael Hartl's tutorial, and are adding a form for the user, you are not that far from the beginning. In any case, `rails destroy model users` will remove all the files related to the model. Then you can re-generate them with the proper name.

Comment: I ran `rails destroy model users` and then `rails generate model user` and have been trying to fix, but no I'm told to run `rake db:migrate` but when I do I get that `table "users" already exists"`.  However, nothing I did created an actual migration file, so I'm having trouble seeing where the issue is.\

Comment: After much effort, I'm 90% of the way there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should rollback the old migration. it hasn't been removed by the `destroy` CLI command (that is expected), but you can generate a new one manually (`rails generate migration custom_name`) and drop the old _users_ table. After that you can run the new migration to re-create the table.